# Using the same query params multiple times in Express/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, axios

I'm working with Express to make an endpoint for my React App to hit. The app is going to allow users to search through multiple companies to find a list of contacts at each company.  They can search for multiple companies at a time, so there will be instances where I'll need to use the same query params multiple times in my get:

https://api.getallthesecompanies.com/people.json?companyname=stackoverflow&companyname=github&companyname=walmart

Right now this is what my code looks like.  It would only pull results for stackoverflow in the above case because it's the first.  It turns all of my companynames into an array instead of objects.  I've tried using brackets before the equals sign and around companyname but the names are still grouped into an array in the same way.

```js
app.get('/api/accounts/people', (req, res) => {
    const accountId = req.query.account_id
    return axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `https://api.getallthesecompanies.com/people.json?account_id=${accountId}`,
    }).then((response) => {
        res.json(response.data)
})}
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem with having an array? Couldn't you map over it and get the contact list for each id?

Comment: I'm sorry - meant to say that it's returning the company names as a single string in an array like this ["stackoverflow, github, walmart"] instead of ["stackoverflow", "github", "walmart"]

Comment: ah, ok. Is that because the query is like "?account_id=id1&id2&id3...? Because I think if the query were like "?account_id=id1&account_id=id2&account_id=id3..." then it would give you an array of separate names. Of course, unless there are commas in some company names, even with the first version you can do account_id[0].split(',') and have a new array of the individual names.

Comment: Thank you! The split worked.  I also needed to add a params object to my get request that takes in the account_ids as an array.  Really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score -1):

## SUGGESTION

Pass the search parameters as an array in the get BODY. I hope you find this helpful.

```
// Add async to route handler   
app.get('/api/accounts/people', async (req, res) => {
    const accountIds = req.body; // Get from body - watch out for edge cases
    try {
        const promises = [];
        accountIds.forEach(id => {
            promises.push(axios.get(`https://api.getallthesecompanies.com/people.json?account_id=${id}`))
        });

        // Resolve all promises (calls to external api)
        const responses = await Promise.all(promises);

        // Merge the responses together
        const mergedResponseData = responses.map(response => response.data).reduce((prev, next) => {
            prev = [...prev, ...next];
            return prev;
        }, []);

        // return data to React App
        res.status(200).json(mergedResponseData);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}
```